# jVectormap gradient background fill

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

In [jVectormap](http://jvectormap.com/) plugin, is there a way to fill the map with gradient background?

I gave a shot by doing this code, but its acknowledging just solid full black.

```
fillColor: {
      linearGradient: {
            stops: [
                 [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                 [1, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)'],
            ]
      }
},
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying the jvectormap source.  I believe the attributes jvectormap recognizes are 'fill' and 'fill-opacity'.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use d3.js u can use this function i founded to set the gradient into a svg

```
function createGradient(svg, id, stops) {
  var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
  var grad = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'linearGradient');
  grad.setAttribute('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
  grad.setAttribute("x1", "0%");
  grad.setAttribute("x2", "0%");
  grad.setAttribute("y1", "0%");
  grad.setAttribute("y2", "100%");
  grad.setAttribute('id', id);

  for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
      var attrs = stops[i];
      var stop = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'stop');
      for (var attr in attrs) {
          if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(attr)) stop.setAttribute(attr, attrs[attr]);
      }
      grad.appendChild(stop);
  }

  var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') || svg.insertBefore(document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'defs'), svg.firstChild);
  return defs.appendChild(grad);
};


function initializeMapColors() {
  createGradient($('svg')[0], 'MyGradient', [{
    offset: '0%',
    'stop-color': '#D96B6C'
  }, {
    offset: '100%',
    'stop-color': '#E35980'
  }]);

  $('path').attr('fill', 'url(#MyGradient)');
};

initializeMapColors();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the gradient element to the `<defs>` element of your map and then link the `fill` attribute to its id. To add the gradient you can use 3d.js library

**Initialize the map and set the fill attribute**

```
$(function () {
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        regionStyle: {
            initial: {
                fill:  'url(#my-gradient)'
            },
        }
    });
});
```

**Add gradient definitions with d3.js**

```
$(function () {
    var defs = d3.select('defs');
    var myGradient = defs.append('linearGradient')
        .attr('id', 'my-gradient')
        .attr('x1', '0%')
        .attr('y1', '100%')
        .attr('x2', '100%')
        .attr('y2', '0%');
    myGradient.append('stop')
        .attr('offset', '0%')
        .attr('style', 'stop-color:rgb(255,255,255)')
        .attr('stop-opacity', 1);
    myGradient.append('stop')
        .attr('offset', '100%')
        .attr('style', 'stop-color:rgb(51,51,51)')
        .attr('stop-opacity', 1);
});
```